# How to avoid docker host & docker container access serial port at the same time?

Tags: docker, serial-port

In linux host, I can use `minicom -D /dev/ttyACM0 -b 115200` to open one serial port, if I execute above command in another terminal, it will show `Device /dev/ttyACM0 is locked`. Above is my expected behavior.

But if I execute `minicom -D /dev/ttyACM0 -b 115200`in host, and then use next command to launch a container:

```
docker run --privileged -idt --name test -v /dev:/dev -v /etc/apt:/etc/apt ubuntu:16.04
```

And in container, I execute `minicom -D /dev/ttyACM0 -b 115200`, it will show I open the serial port successfuly.

Then the phenomenon is: If the serial port print some infomation: E.g. `Hello world!`. The `minicom` in host may get the content `Hello`, while the `minicom` in container may get the content `world!`, it is random.

Anyway, seems two minicom will compete to grab the content of serial port.

Any suggestion to make the behavior same as in host, says if I open serial port in host, then in container. I can get `Device /dev/ttyACM0 is locked` in container, if possible?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally, I got it work myself.

```
docker run --privileged -idt --pid=host --name test -v /var/lock:/var/lock -v /dev:/dev -v /etc/apt:/etc/apt ubuntu:16.04
```

The minicom put its lockfile in /var/lock, now with volume container & host can know eachother which serial is used.